# Filter an array based on another array. (Using React)

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, filtering

The goal is to filter an array based on the slots the user has selected.

For example an array has slots for 7pm-9pm,10pm-12pm and so on.

Now the user selects 7pm-9pm, so now I want to filter the array which have 7ppm-9pm or is the users wants
7pm-9pm and 10pm-11pm so the data should be based on 7pm-9pm and 10pm-11pm

Here is how I store the values

This is the original array

```
data :[ 
       {
        name:"something",
        phone:"another",
        extraDetails : {
            // some more data
           slots : [
               {item:"6PM-7PM"},
               {item:"7PM-8pm}
              ]
            }          
       },{
           // Similarly more array with similar data but somewhere slots might be null
}
      ]
```

Now for example we have this array

```
 slots:[{6PM-7PM,9PM-10PM,11PM-12AM}]
```

Now this should filter all those which includes timeslots of 6PM-7PM,9PM-10PM,11PM-12AM

or if the user selects
  `slots:[{6PM-7PM}]`

We should still get the results that includes 6pm-7pm more or else don't matter.

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd suggest using this for your slots representation for simplicity, but you can alter this approach depending on your actual code:

`slots: ['6PM-7PM', '9PM-10PM', '11PM-12PM']`

Then you can iterate through your data and use filter:

```
const querySlots = ['6PM-7PM', '9PM-10PM', '11PM-12PM'];

const matchedPersonsWithSlots = data.filter( (person) => {
  let i = 0;
  while ( i < person.extraDetails.slots.length ) {
    if (querySlots.includes(person.extraDetails.slots[i]) return true;
    i += 1;
  }

  return false;
});
```

`matchedPersonsWithSlots` will then have all the people that have a slot that matches one of the slots in your query, because if any of the query slots are in a person's list of slots, then it's included in the result set.

**EDIT** to include a different use case

If, however, every slot in the query array must be matched, then the filtering has to be done differently, but with even less code.

```
const matchedPersonsWithAllSlots = data.filter(person =>
  querySlots.every((qSlot)=>person.extraDetails.slots.includes(qSlot)));
```

The above will go through each person in your data, and for each of them, determine whether the person has all of your query slots, and include them in the result list, only if this is true.

Comment: This works, but if the data includes 6PM-7PM but not 9PM-10PM still it returns the value

Comment: @PulkitGupta I've edited the answer to include the case where every slot in the query must be included in a person's available slots.